# How do I stop my screen from constantly locking up in Focal?

Tags: xfce, lightdm, lock-screen

Almost the same question was asked about 9 years ago, but the answer is now stale and did not help me now.

I have a new Xubuntu Focal (LightDM) install on my laptop.  This laptop is actually used as a portable desktop; i.e. it is plugged in unless I'm traveling, which is usually 30 miles or so one-way.  It always runs with 2 large (2048x1152) external monitors (I'm crazy about screen real-estate).  I'm often comparing things on all screens, but now I only get about a minute before they all blank and I have to use a password to open them up again.  Super frustrating.

What I've done so far, all using the whisker menu (an Xubuntu thing) -> Settings:

- set screensaver not to activate, then turned it off completely.
- In LightDM-GTK Greeter Settings -> Misc, set timeout until the screen blanks to "never"
- In Xfce Power Manager -> Display, set all Display Power management sliders to "never", set Reduce after to "never"

I would have hoped any one of these would have done it, but no such luck.  So the question is what did I miss?

Comment: As I was finishing this, I noticed a more recent question from 14.04 had been suggested, and I'm trying it out now.  I'll post an answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.  It's now an hour and a half later (I was watching TV) and the screens and still on.  The secret: Go to "Session and Startup" and un-select two of the apps I tried to reconfigure: "Power Manager" and "Screensaver".

I don't know if you need to do both of them, but it certainly worked for 20.04, six years later.